# Why doesn't type casting List<Widget?> as List<Widget> work if we remove all nulls with .removeNulls() before?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Option A: not working

```
var a = <Widget?>[Container(), null];
a.removeNulls(); 
print(a.length == 1 && a[0] != null) // true
var b = a as List<Widget>; // _CastError (type 'List<Widget?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' in type cast)
```

Option B: working

```
var a = <Widget?>[Container(), null];
a = a.whereType<Widget>().toList(); 
var b = a as List<Widget>; // works fine
```

.removeNull() is part of [fast_immutable_collections](https://pub.dev/packages/fast_immutable_collections)

Comment: Where's `removeNulls` coming from? Please include the code in your question.

Comment: @Riwen assumed it was part of the core library. Just included the info in the post. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the package, but quickly looking up the [extension method](https://pub.dev/documentation/fast_immutable_collections/latest/fast_immutable_collections/FicListExtension/removeNulls.html) shows that's just a wrapper over another function, `removeWhere`, which has nothing to do with nullability.

Try `print(a.runtimeType)` and you'll see `List<Widget?>`. Thus, error thrown is correct.

As to *why* it is the case with the library, only the owner can answer that.

Comment: I was assuming that I can do the type cast if all elements are not Null, even though the runtimeType is still nullable.

Comment: No, you cannot use `as` to cast if the runtime type is not a subtype of that.

Answer (score 0):

A cast with `as` treats as object as a different type.  It does not mutate the object or create a new object.

Suppose that you could cast `List<T?>` as `List<T>` for a non-nullable type `T`.  For example:

```dart
var a = <int?>[0, 1, 2];
var b = a as List<int>; // Pretend that this is legal.
```

now `b` and `a` refer to the same `List` object.  But then consider:

```dart
a.add(null); // Legal. `a` is `List<int?>` and can accept `null`.
var last = b.last; // ???
```

Now you have a situation where `b.last` would refer to a `null` element even though `b` claims to be a `List` of non-nullable elements.  Just because `a` did not have `null` elements at the time you casted it does not mean that it will not have `null` elements in the future.

What you instead must do is to create a new `List` object (e.g. with `whereType<T>().toList()`) or must create a new `List`-like object that performs runtime casts for each element (which is what [`List.cast`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/cast.html) does).